# summarising a process within a sentence

Tags: neologisms

Here, I am describing a small reconstruction process.

I have set of boundary line segments (not connected) relevant to a certain object. I am intersecting adjacent line segments one after the other to connect them and to make a closed polygon. My question is if  I say it with "closed completeness" and then if I summarize my process.

> Successive intersections of adjacent lines form  closed completeness
>   of outer bounds,

Does this clearly explain what I did?
Any idea please.

Answer (score 1):

“Closed completeness” does not intrinsically refer to forming a closed polygon with lines that connect things.  If you want it to have such a meaning, then in an earlier paragraph so define it, in a sentence that starts with “Let the term *closed completeness* refer to ...” or “When we say *closed completeness* we mean ...”.

Note, since *closed completeness* is a singular countable noun, use an article with it ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118983/does-every-countable-noun-have-to-be-preceded-by-an-article)), eg “... form **a** closed completeness of...”.

Note, while *completeness* can be made to work, other words (eg *completion*)  may work better.